# Search results for custom post types shows twice in search in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added this PHP snippet code in functions.php in WordPress to get the Custom post types in search results.  But it shows the results twice in ajax search. Any solution for that?

```
function custom_post_type_search( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_search ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' , 'page' , 'services' ) );
}
   return $query;}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_type_search' );
```

Comment: Shouldn't be related, if you remove this customization, does the problem stop? (btw add && !is_admin() to the if condition).

Comment: @Sagive yes if I remove the code it works fine. When I add && !is_admin() the code doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) an action hook?